# for loop takes to much time to finish

Tags: c#

the below code works fine. The only issue is if i give a array value of length 200,000 its takes too long to complete Approx 1 hour. Below is my code.

I have the data file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxTv8fCpL3ikdF9KOEZ1MWJERkU/view?usp=sharing) which contains data and data2 string values.
data array is arrange in descending and data2 in ascending.

```
public void GetInputs()
{
    string data;
    string data2;
    string[] scores_temp = data.Split(' ');
    int[] scores = Array.ConvertAll(scores_temp, Int32.Parse);

    string[] alice_temp = data2.Split(' ');
    int[] aliceScore = Array.ConvertAll(alice_temp, Int32.Parse);

    var distinctScores = scores.Distinct().ToList();
    int rank = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j <= aliceScore.Length-1; j++)
    {
        for (int i = distinctScores.Count-1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (aliceScore[j] >= distinctScores[i])
            {
                rank = distinctScores.IndexOf(distinctScores[i]);
            }
            else if (aliceScore[j] < distinctScores[i])
            {
                rank = distinctScores.IndexOf(distinctScores[i]);
                rank += 2;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (rank.ToString() == "0") {
            Console.WriteLine(rank.ToString().Replace("0", "1"));
        } else {
            Console.WriteLine(rank); };
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: How long is _too long_?

Comment: approx 1 hour..

Comment: Where do `data` and `data2` get assigned?

Comment: perhaps if you also tell what is your goal with this code so we can give you options.

Comment: That's not really surprising as your method roughly has O(n^2) complexity. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) and that takes some time for about 200'000 items.

Comment: how can I resolve this complexity

Comment: Actually, I think it's worse than O(n^2), because of the IndexOf calls.

Comment: What's your `n` here ? how many inputs are you passing

Comment: you don't need to check for index again inside the loop. You already have the indices - i and j. So skip the `IndexOf` function and you might also simplify the logic inside the loop.

Comment: We need to understand what you are trying to accomplish if we are to help you. It looks to me like Alice has a bunch of scores and you just loop though them and compare them to the table of scores and when you find one that is less than the comparing one, you break. It doesn't really make much sense. What's the goal?

Comment: By the way, you only provided data for the scores. I don't see data2 anywhere.

Comment: Aamir that made a huge difference

Comment: Never mind. I see data2 down there.

Comment: You can also use Parallel.For but you need to make sure you have no dependancies between the variables.

Comment: Minor issue - why are you converting `rank` to a string before comparing? This creates a lot of objects and puts the GC to work for no reason. I don't think that's the major bottleneck here, but it's not helping.

Comment: I think I see what he is trying to do. He has a list of scores for Alice and wants to find out how they rank vs the table of all time scores. He is collecting rankings for each of her scores.

Comment: Without context we cant really give you right solution other than just optimizing your code....

Comment: I have updated my question

Answer (score 6):

This can easily and efficiently be done with a combination of:

Array.Sort(Array):
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tf1f0bc(v=vs.110).aspx

Array.BinarySearch(T[] array, T value):
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cy9f6wb(v=vs.110).aspx

This will give you O(log n) performance (on the search).

Combine this with Linq and you have yourself a pretty fast algorithm.

**UPDATE:**

I was falling asleep yesterday night sorry. Here is an implementation:

```
var sortedScores = Array.ConvertAll(data.Split(' '), int.Parse);
Array.Sort(sortedScores);

var ranks = aliceScore.Select(
    a =>
    {
        var result = Array.BinarySearch(sortedScores, a);
        if (result < 0)
        {
            //Did not find it in array
            var index = ~result;
            if (index > sortedScores.Length - 1)
            {
                //It's greater than all
                return index;
            }
            else
            {
                //Return one up to position it after the larger value
                return index++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Found it, return index
            return result;
        }
    });

foreach (int rankFound in ranks)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Rank: {0}", rankFound);
}
```

I tested it locally and it took 1.05 seconds to process your data, including the Console writes and time elapsed calculation :-)

Answer (score 1):

Replace `rank = distinctScores.IndexOf(distinctScores[i]);` with `rank = i` would simplify your code and give better performance.

Would need further clarification on your goal for other change if any.

Comment: It will only increase performance a bit. But it is still very slow.

Comment: @maxspan that really depends what you want to achieve. From your code I couldn't see what you're doing with `rank`. If it's just a pure output and sequence is not a matter, the answer on sorting provided by @Juan would probably give you better performance. But again, what's the output for?

Answer (score 1):

Here's another non-linq version. I'm not sure of the rank += 2, so maybe this isn't accurate for your requirement. I reversed the elements of the data/scores array. Certainly not as fast as the binary search method, but just a few seconds in a console app.

```
    public static void GetInputs()
    {
        string[] scores_temp = data.Split(' ');
        var distinctScores = scores_temp.Distinct().ToArray();
        int[] scores = (Array.ConvertAll(distinctScores, Int32.Parse)).Reverse().ToArray();

        string[] alice_temp = data2.Split(' ');
        int[] aliceScores = Array.ConvertAll(alice_temp, Int32.Parse);

        int rank = 0;
        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < aliceScores.Length && j < scores.Length; ++i)
        {
            while (aliceScores[i] > scores[j])
                rank = j++;
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Rank {0}: alice {1} -- Index {2}: score {3}", rank, aliceScores[i], j, scores[j]));
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The only change I had to do to increase performance was making sure the inner loop continues from its last loop index.

```
string[] scores_temp = data.Split(' ');
int[] scores = Array.ConvertAll(scores_temp, Int32.Parse);

string[] alice_temp = data2.Split(' ');
int[] aliceScore = Array.ConvertAll(alice_temp, Int32.Parse);

var distinctScores = scores.Distinct().ToList();
int rank = 0;
int innerLoop = distinctScores.Count - 1;
for (int j = 0; j <= aliceScore.Length-1; j++)
{
    for (int i = innerLoop; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        innerLoop = i;
        if (aliceScore[j] >= distinctScores[i])
        {
            rank = i;
        }
        else if (aliceScore[j] < distinctScores[i])
        {
            rank = i;
            rank += 2;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (rank.ToString() == "0") {
        Console.WriteLine(rank.ToString().Replace("0", "1"));
    } else {
        Console.WriteLine(rank); };
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Sort them, then just work with indeces! If you know that yours arrays are sorted, you can check position of each `aliceScore` in `distinctScores`. Then you will know how many `distinctScores` are upwards or below, and do whatever you want.